# Selenium - Sending text to a formatted input

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium WebDriver in Java, I am trying to send text to a formatted input that looks like this

`___-__-____`

As you might have guessed, this is a Social Security field.  Anyhow, when I try to send keys to the field using Selenium, it is not having troubles locating the element but it doesn't send any keys and tries to move on to the next step in the automation.

I am locating the element `by.ID` and it has an element `id` of `ssn` (which is unique to this element), so I know the problem here isn't with my selection methods.

Here is the HTML & absolute XPath for the element:

```
Absolute Xpath: html/body/div[2]/p[3]/input

<body>
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="/assets/images/logo.png">
        </div>
            <br>
            <p id="errorsField" class="hidden">
                <strong></strong>
            </p>

        <input class="hidden" type="text" id="clientUrlPart" value="bigco" />
        <input class="hidden" type="text" id="is-self-registration" value="0" />

        <div id="login">

            <p>
                <label for="firstName" class="required">First Name</label>
                <input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="firstName" maxlength="25" value="">
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="lastName" class="required">Last Name</label>
                <input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="lastName" maxlength="25" value="">
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="ssn" class="required">Social Security Number</label>
                <input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="ssn" value="" filledSSN="">
            </p>


              <div id="newAccountInfo" class="hidden">

                <div id="self-registration" class="hidden">
...
</body>
```

Any thoughts?

Relevant Code:

```
public static void registerEmployee(String firstName, String lastName, String ssn, String dateOfBirth, String address,
String city, String state, String zip, String phone, String username, String password) {
    SeleniumCommands.waitVisibleIdAndSendKeys(FIRSTNAME, firstName);
    SeleniumCommands.waitVisibleIdAndSendKeys(LASTNAME, lastName);
    SeleniumCommands.waitVisibleIdAndSendKeys(SSN, ssn);
    ...
}

public static final String SSN = "ssn";

public static void waitVisibleIdAndSendKeys(String id, String keys) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(id))).sendKeys(keys);
}
```

Comment: What if you send only the first part of the SSN?

Comment: Also, can you make the problem reproducible for us? Thanks.

Comment: It won't send anything to the field, but it acts like it does.  I'll try to add what I can to help out, but I've written several methods to abstract out Selenium specific commands, so just let me know where you need more information once I've added the code to the original.

Comment: I've added code to the original, let me know what else you might need or be looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: have you tried first clicking on the element before sendKeys()?

Comment: I just tried that and it still isn't sending keys.

Comment: @lmcphers what if you programmatically set the SSN. E.g. `js.executeScript("arguments[0].filledssn = '123-45-6789';", elm);`?

Comment: Here is what I added:

`SeleniumCommands.myDriver.executeScript("arguments[0].filledssn = '123-45-6789';", ssn);` and it still is not sending the keys, but tries to move on to the next step in the automation as if it did.

Comment: @lmcphers okay, thanks for trying. Is it a public site and we can try it out too?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so :( I'll keep poking around with it I suppose. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @lmcphers okay, could you provide an HTML representation of the input element and surrounding and parent elements? Also, look for other invisible inputs that can actually be used for storing the SSN.

Comment: @alecxe I have added more HTML and an absolute XPath reference for the element to the post.  There are no other references to the social security number in the HTML except after you click a register button which asks you to Reenter SSN which is a field with ID "reenterSSN" so should not be clashing there.

Comment: @alecxe Just as an update, I was told that the input field uses a jQuery mask function.  Is that helpful to you in solving this issue?

Comment: @lmcphers yeah, clicking before sending keys should help, see: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2377. You may also try add a small delay between the actions.

Comment: That worked, I tried clicking it it beforehand and it didn't work.  I added a wait and that seemed to do the trick. Woops! Thanks for your help all.  If you submit an answer, I'll upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I have experienced pre-formatted text boxes like this require individual keys to be input one at a time, rather than how selenium/webdriver typically does it. Try creating three statements to input one number each to see if it likes that. If it does, you can do a for loop for x in ssn to iterate through the characters without splitting them first, or something like that.

Comment: Sorry Justin, but this didn't work for me.  Thanks for trying, though!